# memory used by JBoss using java code

Tags: java, jboss

i want to made java program in which i need to a code java allows to know the memory used by JBOSS.
how can i know the jboss memory usage using a code java?

please can you help me?
thanks

Comment: off-top. Why do you need the memory managment in jboss?

Answer (score 2):

Jboss server offers its system information such as memory usage through [JMX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/javamanagement-140525.html). The `jboss.system:type=ServerInfo` MBean provides several attributes that can be used to monitor the thread and memory usage in a JBoss instance.

Learn more about the JBoss JMX interfaces and MBeans: http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Additional_Services-Memory_and_Thread_Monitoring.html

Comment: @ofloflofl Have tried connecting to jboss jmx server through jconsole and see what mbeans are avialbale, the name might have changed for JBoss7 but i expect an mbean providing this info. The default jmx port is 1090 i believe to connect to jmx server through jconsole.